# metric space incomplete

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

Good day, please how show that C[a,b] with norm $\left \| f \right \|=(\int_{a}^{b}f^{p}(x)dx)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ is not complete, $p\geq 1$. Can I do it with $g_{n}=(\int_{a}^{t}f_{n}^{p}dt)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ adecuate?

Comment: Do you mean $(\int_a^b|f|^pdx)^{1/p}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you a hint for the case $[a,b]=[-1,1]$. Consider $g_n\in C[-1,1]$ such that $g_n(t)=nt$ for $t\in [-1/n,1/n]$ and $g_n(t)=-1$ on $[-1,-1/n)$ and $g_n(t)=1$ on $(1/n,1]$. Show that 
1). $\{g_n\}$ constitute a Cauchy sequence as to the $p$-norm. 
2). If $g_n\to g\in C[-1,1]$ in the $p$-norm, then there is no way to define the value of $g(0)$.

Comment: @Arthur oops. I'll edit. Thanks for spotting the silly mistake.

Comment: but for example, seeing when is cauchy, how resolve an integral as $\int_{a}^{b}(f_{m}-g_{n})^{\pi }dx$, with irrational potence?

Comment: @mathreda Are you concerned about measurability? It doesn't matter what value $p$ takes in $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: formally, how to explain? I know that must resolve the integral for justify that is Cauchy sequence

Comment: @mathreda It can be computed directly that, assuming $n<m$, $$\|g_m-g_n\|_p=(\int_{[-1,1]} |g_n-g_m|^p)^\frac1p\le (2\int_{[0,1/n]}|1|^p)^\frac1p=(\frac2n)^\frac1p.$$

Comment: please a question, is not $n\geq m$

Comment: @mathreda then just replace $n$ with $m$.